# how can i show advanced custom fields plugin fields show in front end classipress form

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using word press theme classipress, now i want to add multiple dynamic drop downs which relay on each other.
like country drop down,when any country is selected another drop down appears that selected country cities.for this im using advanced custom fields plugin,
it works on back end,but i don't know how to display these fields in front end.
I am trying this link but could not help out http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-a-front-end-form/

Comment: You have to post the code you're working with. See [ask] and [How to include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
For dynamic drop down you need to use ajax with wordpress

I am explain all step which help you to create dynamic drop down country with city.

Please follow below steps:
Step : 1 
At first, Create Categories: Parent and Sub category from wp admin.
Step : 2

Create a template in WordPress( I am not going in details of what are the templates of WordPress and how they process in WordPress themes) in which we will implement ajax functionality. Open a new php file and save it with any name like I saved it with implement-ajax.php
Add the following code in the newly created page.

<?php
/*
Template Name: Implement Ajax
*/
get_header();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<style type="text/css">
#content{width:auto; height:400px; margin:50px;}
</style>
<div id="content">
<?php
wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Main Categories&name=main_cat');
?>
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" disabled="disabled"></select>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>


Step :3

Now add jquery code in template 

$(function(){
  $('#main_cat').change(function(){
  var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();
    // call ajax
  $("#sub_cat").empty();
     $.ajax({
    url:"bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type:'POST',
    data:'action=my_special_action&main_catid=' + $mainCat,
     success:function(results)
     {
    //  alert(results);
    $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#sub_cat").append(results);
        }
       });
  }
);
});


Step:6 Now add this code in function.php 


function implement_ajax() {
if(isset($_POST['main_catid']))
            {
            $categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
              foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
                $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
                $option .= '</option>';
              }

              echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Scegli...</option>'.$option;
            die();
            `enter code here`} // end if
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'implement_ajax');//for users that are not logged in.

Step :5

Now create a new page in the dashboard and assign the template to it.
```